# How to create package that will import jobs in Control-M?

Tags: control-m

I am very new to **Control-M** and have been trying to find an answer for this question for a while now.
All of my jobs are on GitHub (json or xml) and I want to **send them to Control-M** but Control-M is **not installed on my computer** (it is installed on the computer of our team scheduling admin).

From my understanding so far, I need to export my files from GitHub in **xml or json** format for them to be 'readable' my Control-M.
I **cannot install Control-M Automation API workbench nor a Control-M instance** on my computer (I am **not allowed to install anything from the internet** on my computer). How can I send all of my jobs to Control-M and **import/load** them into Control-M that is not on my computer? Do I need to write a **package** to import the jobs in the scheduler?

Apologies if my question is very stupid. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install the Control-M fat client on your desktop. If your admin doesn't allow you to do that they really aren't allowing you to do your job. Alternatively they should give you access to a server where the fat client is installed.

The fat client has options to import and export the scheduling tables and calendars in XML format.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks a lot for getting back to me so quickly. I've asked my admin and they'll allow me to install CTM fat client. I'm new to this-are my job scripts supposed to be imported separately from the sched tables and calendars or w/in the same code? where can I find templates of what sched tables and calendars should look like? Do you know where I can find more info on the "fat client"? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, Control-M simply launches the scripts so you will have to migrate those yourself. The only exception to this is if you are running "embedded" scripts (where the code is included within the Control-M job definition itself). However you can often find that jobs don't reference a script, for example you get 256 characters to play with in the command field and that can often be enough to complete the task without external scripts coming into play.

Comment: Also note that for the scheduling tables and calendars are imported/exported via different processes (you will see buttons for these in the fat client or use the specific command). And the Help section in the fat-client is good for beginner info and includes videos (some hosted on the BMC YouTube channel).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! That's really helpful :)